# Cannot build Elastic libbeat according to the developer guide

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, cookiecutter

I am following the "Developer Guide: Creating a New Beat" and trying to develop my own beat. However, I have encountered a problem in the step "Building and Running the Beat". After I execute "make", I get the following output is:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `vendor/github.com/elastic/beats/generate/beat/examplebeat/beater/{{', needed by `countbeat'.  Stop.
```

There are still some directories named {{cookiecutter.xxx}} within the generated project directory. I do not know it is my setup problem or anything else, any help is appreciated, thank you.

The configuration of my building machine:
Ubuntu 14.04
GNU Make 3.81
Python 2.7.6
Cookiecutter 1.4.0
gccgo (Ubuntu 4.9.3-0ubuntu4) 4.9.3

Comment: Are you sure you have run `cookiecutter` properly?

Answer (score 0):

May be there are some error in checking out the code. I still don't know why but everything is alright after I delete and check out the code again.